# ServiceNow Azure SSO integration

Tags: azure, servicenow

I have been trying to create an SSO from Azure to ServiceNow. However, I am stuck at this error.

> User: 6pGO5pzp9boSuAj82Cj6bK8aBeet9HKUdhNfUzalsKI= not found Ensure
> that the user you are trying the test connection with is present in
> the system. Ensure that 'User Field' property value corresponds to the
> value set in the IDP returned through 'Subject NameID' in the
> response.

I have tried different ID Policies. All of them give the same error though. This is the one I am using

`urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:2.0:nameid-format:transient`

Can anyone helpout a little?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting this same error until I changed the NameID Policy to urn:oasis:names:tc:SAML:1.1:nameid-format:emailAddress

User Field (under advanced): user_name

Type cache.do in filter navigator. Press enter.
Clear your browser cache.

Test connection.

See if that works and let me know.